# Save both current and new version of post meta

Tags: post-meta, duplicates

I want to save two versions of my custom meta box data called "sidebar". I want to compare a new and old version of this data later on, so that is why I want to save a copy of the current "sidebar" to a field called "sidebar_old", just before saving a new version. Here's my attempt at doing just that:

```
add_action('pre_post_update', 'content_old_save');

function content_old_save() {
    global $post;
    $sidebar_old = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebar', true);

    update_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebar_old", $sidebar_old); // current/old sidebar
}
```

This is how I save the new version:

```
add_action('save_post', 'sidebar_title_update');

function sidebar_title_update($post_id) {
    global $post;

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return $post_id;
    }

    update_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebar", $_POST["sidebar"]); // new sidebar
}
```

Thing is, only the new sidebar value is inserted into the database, to both "sidebar" and "sidebar_old", so somehow the new value is already inserted into the db even before pre_post_update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that could be caused by post revision being saved, and you should use `wp_insert_post_data` anytime you want to do something before the post is saved, here is an example plugin i just cooked up to test it and it looks like this:

[image]

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: wpse37901
Plugin URI: http://en.bainternet.info
Description: answer to  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37901/save-both-current-and-new-version-of-post-meta
Version: 1.0
Author: Bainternet
Author URI: http://en.bainternet.info
*/



add_action('save_post', 'sidebar_title_update');

function sidebar_title_update($post_id) {
    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpse37901_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;


    // Check permissions
    if ( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
    {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
            return;
    }else{
        return;
    }

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

    if (isset($_POST['sidebar'])){      
        //save new
        update_post_meta($post_id, "sidebar", $_POST["sidebar"]); // new sidebar
    }
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse37901_add_custom_box' );

function wpse37901_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'wpse37901_sectionid',
        __( 'wpse37901 test field'),
        'wpse37901_inner_custom_box',
        'post' 
    );
}

add_action('wp_insert_post_data','wpse37901_store_revision');

function wpse37901_store_revision($data,$postarr){
    global $post;
    if ($data['post_type'] !== 'revision' && isset($_POST['sidebar'])){
        //save old
            //get last saved data
        $sidebar_old = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebar', true);
            //only store if value updated
        if ($_POST['sidebar'] != $sidebar_old){
                //get stored revisions
            $sidebar_old_saved = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebar_old', true);
                //add last to revisions
            $sidebar_old_saved[] = array('date' => date("j, n, Y  H:i:s"), 'value' =>$sidebar_old);
                //update revisions array
            update_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebar_old", $sidebar_old_saved);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

function wpse37901_inner_custom_box( $post ) {
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'wpse37901_noncename' );

    $sidebar_saved = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebar', true);
    // The actual fields for data entry
    echo '<label for="sidebar">';
    _e("For testing");
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="sidebar" name="sidebar" value="'.$sidebar_saved.'" size="25" />';
    $sidebar_revisions = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebar_old', true);
    if (!empty($sidebar_revisions)){
        if (is_array($sidebar_revisions)){
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($sidebar_revisions as $r){
                echo '<li>'.$r['date'].' : '.$r['value'].'</li>'; 
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Glad i could help :)