# A correct hook for saving meta boxes data

Tags: metabox, hooks, save-post

Nothing happens when I do the `var_dump()` in a callback on post save.

Here are the hooks I've tried:

- `save_post` as shown [in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)
- `pre_post_update` as suggested [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/save_post-not-working-getting-called#post-2335557)
- `wp_insert_post_data` found [in this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37901/save-both-current-and-new-version-of-post-meta)

The code is rather simple:

```
function my_meta_boxes_save( $post_id ) {
    var_dump($_POST); exit;
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    //some other checks here etc.
    //update_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_name', 'meta_value');
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_meta_boxes_save' ); // also tried the other hooks above
```

I need this to trigger every time the post is saved, including the cases when only the meta data is changed, and not the post content itself (this is where `save_post` fails).

Am I missing something? Any suggestions?

**Update**: @Dan it looks like `save_post` is triggered only if the post content was updated. I need to add about 10 meta boxes which might be edited without modifying the post content. In that case, when saved, `save_post` won't be triggered, my callback won't be called and the modifications entered in the custom meta boxes will be discarded.

**Update**: I am saving the meta boxes using the `update_post_meta` function. It was just removed from the code above so it looks less messy. I'm ok with users hitting the "Update" button, in fact, this is what I'm after. I do not need any ajax here or automatic save etc. I just need to make sure that my `my_meta_boxes_save()` callback is going to be called every time the users hit 'Update' or 'Publish' regardless of whether the post content itself was updated or not.

Right now I am debugging this, so I don't even need the meta save to happen - the `var_dump()` should just output the data, this way showing me that the callback was triggered, but it doesn't.

Comment: I always use the save_post hook. If you're using a custom meta box this can't be saved without hitting the "update" button so I don't understand what you mean when you say "I need this to trigger every time the post is saved, including the cases when only the meta data is changed, and not the post content itself (this is where save_post fails)."

Comment: @Dan, please see the question updated

Comment: How are you saving the meta box content without calling the save_post hook? AJAX?

Comment: If you want to save metaboxes even if post is not changed add a button "save" to your boxes and handle it with ajax.

Comment: @G.M. thanks but this feels too complicated. The metaboxes should be saved when the post.php form is submitted

Comment: @Dan I did try the `save_post` hook but again, it is not always triggered

Comment: Well, you know, this is WordPress *Development* and so I suggest *development* task, and it's not very complicated... Also, when post is submitted `save_post` should be triggered. Please show us your code.

Comment: If you want to save the meta boxes when the post form is submitted, I think save_post is correct, and it should always fire. Make sure the WP dubug tools are turned on and error_log() when the save_post hook is called?

Comment: If I put the code you posted here in my test environment in `functions.php` when I hit the button "Update" **without changing anything** in the post, I got `$_POST` dumped and request exit. So the code posted here work. Your problem is somewhere else, or maybe the file where this code is placed is not loaded during a post save action.

Comment: Right I see, thanks for pointing out! I'll look into whether some other plugins are overwriting the hook or something.

Comment: You **need** ajax if you want data is saved without the user click "update". If it's fine for you that data get updated when user click "Update" than, yes, you don't need ajax. But if you read my previous comment the code you posted **work** when user click "Update" even if the post is not modified. Your problem is somewhere else.